# Local IIS Web Config error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type add with unique key attribute Path set to '*'

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am trying to run my asp.net app.When I run this I am getting the Internal server 500 error. I am using Local iis Web server.

While I traced error details I am getting this error:

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type add with unique key attribute Path set to '*'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.